# Mapkit with annotations and IBAction to Load New View on Pin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have recently attended an introductory course in using the iPhone SDK and the Objective-C programming language. The course didn't really go into great detail on using Mapkit and the likes of annotations etc..

I am required to create an application which uses the inbuilt Framework MapKit, I need to be able to generate a map based on user input from the super view which then queries an external NSURL and reads either jSON or XML data type output from that URL to populate the Map's Pins (annotations).

These Pins need to have an IBAction or IBOutlet to load another sub view based on what the user has tapped to reveal more information on that particular entry - which needs to be stored in memory until viewDidUnload or loading a particular sub or parent view.

So as you can imagine this seems terribly daunting in order to find out, I have trolled Google and this site for answers and I can't seem to find what I am looking for - hence this post.

If anyone could assist or point me in the right direction that would be deeply appreciated!

I hope this post makes sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at iTunes U -> CS193P - Fall 2010 -> Lecture 14. Core Location and Mapkit
[Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774)

Hope this helps you going in the right direction